# What command to use to transfer file from one server to another server

Tags: jmeter

I want to automate the process of transferring files between servers that is done using WinSCP. Can we automate this process through jmeter using OS process sampler. Please help me with the command to transfer files and how to connect to servers using jmeter and transfer files.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Jmeter Plugin *jmeter-ssh-sampler*  for this:**

And then can use SCP command to transfer file from one server to another server.

*To copy a file from a local to a remote system run the following command:*

**Commad** : *scp file.txt remote_username@10.10.0.2:/remote/directory*

Below is the link to the plugin:

[jmeter-ssh-sampler link](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler)

Comment: thanks for help, but i have doubt i want to copy the file from one server to another . not from local to remote server. Should i add scp command in SSH sampler. Please help me with steps in detail. I am new to this.

Comment: What you can do you can create ssh connection using the above plugin to the server from where you want to transfer the file and then run the SCP command

Comment: scp file.txt remote_username@remote_host:path_where_you_want_to_copy_file